# Can't start Rails server on 3.2.6 system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a major issue trying to start my Rails project. I am taking a rails 4.0.0 project and trying to run it on a Rails 3.2.6 system. My work environment uses a Rails 3.2.6 environment and my system at home where I was working from home (a mac mini) uses rails 4. I have since started using my Linux laptop which has Rails 3.2.6 like my employer uses.

Here is my error trace:

```
ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/RoR_projects/mock_devices2$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:260:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:260:in `root'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1317:in `root'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/routes.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config.ru:4:in `require'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /home/ironmantis7x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_testbed1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/RoR_projects/mock_devices2$
```

Here is my environment.rb file:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
MockDevices2::Application.initialize!
```

And here is my boot.rb file:

```
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
require 'thread'
```

my gem list is as follows:

```
actionmailer (3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4)
jbuilder (1.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.1)
json (1.8.0)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
multi_json (1.7.7)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.6)
railties (3.2.6)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.2.0)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

Comment: " I am taking a rails 4.0.0 project and trying to run it on a rails 3.2.6 system. " -- wat? is this a typo?

Comment: if your taking a 4.0.0 rails project you should upgrade the rails on your system to match the project, using RVM or a fresh install

Comment: i can't upgrade th eproduction system at my job to rails 4.0.0. they have sai dthat they are not going to do this at this time. SO, I must use rails 3.2.6. No this is not a typo. I developed a project on a rails 4.0.0 system (which was a mistake) and I need to try to run the same project on a rails 3.2.6 system. I need help figuring out what to fix and how to fix it so that it runs. I am very new to ruby/rails. Please understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post your routes.rb? Seems like the problem is at

```
from /home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/routes.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

This happened to me and the problem was that I used

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

instead of

```
root to: 'welcome#index'
```

and rails 3 doesn't like that

Comment: @halfer: you decided to contribute by fixing spelling mistakes and grammar mistakes instead of providing technical insight and ways to actually fix the code and provide a solution to the actual problem. It is very bad for us as aspiring developers and developers in practice when we run into people like you that do this. Please find a more sound technical way to boost your reputation on here besides fixing english grammar mistakes. Can you next time actually make code contributions?

Comment: @Ninjarabbi: your colution fixed my issue. Thank you.